# QGIS - Export GPX Layer With Python Resulting In No Data

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

When I manually export my route, I get the route as a GPX format and it is a valid export.

When running the below code I am getting a 1 Kb file with no route data.

```
# Select a single or multiple layers and then run this script
print("Running Export Script")
path = "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/"
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    layerName = layer.name()
    pathToFile = path + layerName + ".gpx"
    print(layerName)
    _writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
        layer,
        pathToFile,
        "utf-8",
        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),
        "GPX", 
        onlySelected=True,
        datasourceOptions=["GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=ON"],
        layerOptions=["FORCE_GPX_ROUTE=YES"])
```

**[Answer]** Here is what I ended up with:

```
# Select a single or multiple layers and then run this script
print("Running Export Script")

path = "C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/"

layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    layerName = layer.name()
    file_path = os.path.join(path, f'{layer.name()}.gpx')

    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(
        file_path, 
        'utf-8', 
        layer.fields(), 
        QgsWkbTypes.LineString, 
        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),
        "GPX")
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        ok = writer.addFeature(ft)

    if(writer.NoError == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError):
        print("GPX saved: " + str(layerName))
        qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("GPX saved: " + str(layerName), Qgis.Success)
    else:
        print("Error creating: " + str(layerName))
        qgis.utils.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error creating: " + str(layerName), Qgis.Critical)

    del writer
```

Comment: Please put everything as an answer, instead of extending your initial question ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through my notes & code snippets and found that I have had a similar problem in the past. Try the following example, using a `QgsVectorFileWriter` object instead of calling the `WriteAsVectorFormat` method (with recent versions you should be using `WriteAsVectorFormatV3` in any case).

```py
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads"
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
for layer in layers:
    file_path = os.path.join(path, f'{layer.name()}.gpx')
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(file_path, 'utf-8', layer.fields(), QgsWkbTypes.LineString, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326),"GPX")
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        ok = writer.addFeature(ft)
#        print(ok)# Check that addFeature() operation returned True
    del writer
```

Edit: According to the [docs](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a906aad9d969d8da69dacb8b8e06f9261) the `create()` method should now be used to construct a `QgsVectorFileWriter` object.

```py
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads"
print(os.path.exists(path))
layers = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = 'GPX'
options.fileEncoding = 'utf-8'

for layer in layers:
    file_path = os.path.join(path, f'{layer.name()}.gpx')
    print(file_path)
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.create(file_path,
                                        layer.fields(),
                                        QgsWkbTypes.LineString,
                                        QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(28353),
                                        QgsProject.instance().transformContext(),
                                        options)
    for ft in layer.getFeatures():
        ok = writer.addFeature(ft)
        print(ok)

    del writer
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick. I tried adding in some error handling as well but not  able to test as my routes are all good.